# How to use my if/else statement in a for loop with arrays?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, if-statement

I have code that compares userinput from `EditText` to the correct translation(`String[] answers`). Now i wrote a `if/else` statement but I'm trying to put that in a `for` loop. Otherwise I need to write over 30 statements. just with a few numbers different.

Now I have came up with the following 'basis':

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
>
>         if (Uinput[].equals(answers[])) {
>             edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
>         } else {
>             edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
>         }
>     }
> ```

What do I need to put between the brackets([]) as it wont allow it empty, and further any recommendations or changes? Thanks in advance.

Code sample of what I'm currently using:

`private String[] answers = {"daylight", "task"};`

`private EditText edit1;`

`this.edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);`

`String Uinput[] = {edit1.getText().toString()};`

```
//        Comparison 1
        if (Uinput[0].equals(answers[0])) {
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        }
        else {
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
```

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase. `Uinput` should be `uinput`.

Comment: Changed it in mine code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You can simply use `Arrays.asList` e.g.

```
if (Arrays.asList(answers).contains(edit1.getText().toString())) {
    edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
} else {
    edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respons, With this code it works the same as the code I currently have, but because i have 34 comparisons it rquires me to write it 34 times thats why I want to loop it. But thx for the effort.

Comment: what do you mean by 'i have 34 comparisons'?

Comment: @J.Doe You don't need to write it 34 times. You have one `contains` method which will check every element of the array.

Comment: @JayeshBabu I use the code in total 34 times as I have 34 comparisons

Comment: @MuratK. Yes, but I have 34 `edit`s (`edit1, edit2` etc.) And I 'need' to check for one specific element as if the user mix up the order of answers it still would set it to true, as it checks all elements of the array list.

Comment: @J.Doe Then put the `if` statement from this answer in a loop.

Comment: @J.Doe are you saying you have 34 of these EditText variables? why not make an array of them?

Comment: @SurajRao as I don't now aworkaround the NullPointerException I get then. I already tried it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My question is how do I make a good working loop with the if/else statement.

Comment: @J.Doe Put your `EditText`s in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should put i into the square brackets

```
for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
        if (Uinput[i].equals(answers[i])) { // USE i in the brackets
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        } else {
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: This does not work, when I use this it only checks the first one and only gives false. Even when correct.